# How to darken the background image in CSS?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a jumbotron from bootstrap and I want to darken its background without touching the text which is entered in it. Is there a way to do such a thing?

I have looked everywhere, but all solutions I've found darken the text as well.

What I have so far:

```css
.mainJumbotron {
    margin: 0px;
    height: 250px;
    text-align: center;
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/qj2w73W.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron mainJumbotron">
    <h1 style="">Hakkımızda</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: There you go. I have added the code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try something like this:

In your `jumbotron` class, give it a little more CSS by adding `position:relative;` to it if it's not already there.  That will allow the next step to be positioned inside of that box.

Then, add an `:after` pseudo element. with the following CSS

```
.jumbotron:after {
    content:"";
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:1 /*Added this in the updated */
}
```

the `background-color` shade is controlled by the final value.  `0.5` is 50% opacity, raise to 1 or lower to 0 to get your desired darkness.

**UPDATE** What has been pointed out is that anything inside of the box is covered by the new pseudo element.  Here's a cheap fix.  Add `z-index:1;` to your `:after` alement, then add the below

```
.jumbotron > * {
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
}
```

Thanks to cale_b https://jsfiddle.net/e8c3ex0h/3/

Comment: didn’t work either :(

Comment: try adding `z-index:1` or higher to the `:after`, just to see if it's behind

Comment: This does not do what you think it does: https://jsfiddle.net/e8c3ex0h/2/ (I've done both `before` and `after`, same result.

Comment: @cale_b Your example looks like it works fine.  What am I missing?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ritizawinu/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: The heading is also dimmed.  Can't get the heading to "pop" white above the jumbotron.  (Checking in FF, Mac).

Comment: @cale_b, Ah, I see. Let me try some stuff

Comment: @cale_b, I've updated your fiddle to work: https://jsfiddle.net/e8c3ex0h/3/, Will update the answer

Comment: @EgeKaanGürkan, I have found a solution and am editing my answer now

Comment: Yep - got it.  Need position on the h1 for z-index to work.  Always forget that.... https://jsfiddle.net/e8c3ex0h/4/

Comment: No need for z-index: https://jsfiddle.net/e8c3ex0h/5/

Comment: @miro, Great point. It should sort itself out when you add a position to the inner elements.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked!!

Comment: @EgeKaanGürkan, You got it!  Please check John's answer though - it is better practice it seems.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following in you CSS to see if you get the desired result

```
    #element {
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 50px 100px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 50px 100px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
box-shadow: inset 0px 50px 100px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

Comment: Not quite the thing i want :/

Comment: So you want like an overlay?

Comment: I want the background picture to be darkened a bit so that the text in front can be read clearly.

Comment: So you want to adjust the contrast of the image?

Comment: Not quite. Imagine a semi opaque dark rectangle placed on top of the image.

Comment: Cool you provide a screenshot for me? Just so that I can give you the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

This is how to do it :

```css
body, h1 {
    margin: 0;
}

.mainJumbotron {
    margin: 0px;
    height: 250px;
    text-align: center;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)),
                      url(http://i.imgur.com/qj2w73W.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}

h1 {
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron mainJumbotron">
    <h1 style="">Hakkımızda</h1>
</div>
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/2cdhbrsy/1/))